# Why Kotlin class does not need to open in Spring Boot anymore

Tags: spring, kotlin

In a latest video about Kotlin and Spring Boot: [Spring Tips: Bootiful Kotlin Redux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3yI_YhG5pk). The `Application` class of Spring Boot looks like:

```
class SpringBootKotlinApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

}
```

I remember a Kotlin has to be annotated as `open` in Spring Boot.

```
open class SpringBootKotlinApplication
```

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90WRtrbRi0Y).

So why it is not necessary to be annotated `open` now? Spring Boot does need to extend the Application class now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a look at one of the speaker’s sample projects like [this](https://github.com/joshlong/flux-flix-service/blob/master/kotlin/flux-flix-service/pom.xml), you will notice a **compiler plugin**, in this case `kotlin-maven-allopen`. It’s described in the official [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html):

> For instance, when you use Spring, you don't need all the classes to be **open**, but only classes annotated with specific annotations like @Configuration or @Service. All-open allows to specify such annotations.

As `SpringBootAnnotation`, as a meta `annotation`, is fulfilling that condition, there’s no need to make the class `open` in the source code since the compiler does it behind the scenes.